# vb.net unzip multiple zip files in a folder

Tags: vb.net, extract, unzip

Does anyone know the best method to unzip multiple zip files in a folder to one location.  Is it best to use the codeplex dll for instance, or try and get the latest .net framework to work? thanks, VBvirg.

Comment: What zip library are you using, or invoking a command-line program?

Comment: Im tring to use the standard one but its not appearing for me.  So now am looking at ionic.

Comment: What "standard one"? .NET has multiple compression options for handling zip files (and other schemes) in the BCL.

Comment: I was looking to go down the route of Zipfile that comes with dot net 4.5 when i try to use import system.io.compression.zipfile i dont get the option of zipfile after compression.  As you can tell im new to this hence my name VBvirg.

Comment: Oh and im using vb express 2013,

Comment: I have also been looking at codeplex ionic.

Answer (score 0):

NET4.5 has ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory (Import System.IO.Compression.ZipFile) so you can enumerate zip archives in a folder (Directory.GetFiles(Path, "*.zip") and extract each one. For older frameworks, I recommend SharpZipLib. Both do same job, but I would stick to native methods where possible as its one less library to distribute.

Comment: Im using express 2013 but i dont get the option for ZipFile under Import System.IO.Compression i get the following options, CompressionMode, DeflateStream and GZipstream.

Comment: Try adding reference to System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Doesn't allow .filesystem only the ones above for some reason.  I bet im doing something stupid.

Comment: Hi Daniel, if found the issue my VS was looking at the wrong .net framework.

I played around with the following

ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory("c:\logs\kpmgcore1logs201406010000.zip", "c:\logs")

Which works great, my assumption is now i need to add a For each iteration to loop through each file and extract them individually? would that be correct?

Answer (score 0):

Way after the last correspondence, but if anyone who stumbles across this is still interested, here is how to do it.

Make sure you're using .NET Framework 4.5 or above and that you have included references to `System.IO.Compression` and `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.

```
Imports System.IO.Compression

' returns number of archives successfully unpacked
Function unpackAll(pat As String) As Integer
    unpackAll = 0
    If Not Directory.Exists(pat) Then Return unpackAll
    For Each zfn In Directory.GetFiles(pat, "*.zip")
        Try
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zfn, pat)
            unpackAll += 1
        Catch ex As exception
        End Try
    Next
End Function
```

Note that this unpacks everything to the same folder as where the .zip archives exist.  It might be more useful to do this:

```
' returns number of archives successfully unpacked
Function unpackAll(pat As String, Optional destPath As String = "") As Integer
    unpackAll = 0
    If Not Directory.Exists(pat) Then Return unpackAll
    If destPath = "" Then destPath = pat
    If Not Directory.Exists(destPath) Then
        Try
            Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End If
    If Not Directory.Exists(destPath) Then Return unpackAll
    For Each zfn In Directory.GetFiles(pat, "*.zip")
        Try
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zfn, destPath)
            unpackAll += 1
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next
End Function
```

And then call it like this:

```
unpackAll("C:\logs","C:\unpacked_logs")
```

If it doesn't matter how many archives are unpacked, then the function can be re-written as a sub:

```
' attempts to unpack all the .zip archives in a folder
Sub unpackAll(pat As String)
    If Not Directory.Exists(pat) Then Exit Sub
    For Each zfn In Directory.GetFiles(pat, "*.zip")
        Try
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zfn, pat)
        Catch ex As exception
        End Try
    Next
End Function
```

it is desired to obtain the number of files (attempted to be) unpacked instead of the number of archives, one could change this line:

```
unpackAll += 1
```

to this:

```
unpackAll += ZipFile.Open(zfn, ZipArchiveMode.Read).Entries.Count
```